# BCS Managed Client Code Get all method instances

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, bcs, external-content-type, client-object-model, external-data-column

When using the class

```
Microsoft.BusinessData.MetadataModel.Entity entity;
```

does anyone know how to get all the External Content type operation method instances so i can dynamically pass the value to the method:

```
entity.GetFilters("readListMethodInstanceName");
```

Currently I have the following working but the method instance name is hardcoded.

```
 string readListInstanceName = "Read List";
      Microsoft.BusinessData.MetadataModel.Entity entity = clientContext.Web.GetEntity(businessDataField.EntityNamespace, businessDataField.EntityName);

      Microsoft.BusinessData.MetadataModel.LobSystem lobSystem = entity.GetLobSystem();
      Microsoft.BusinessData.MetadataModel.Collections.LobSystemInstanceCollection lobSystemInstanceCollection = lobSystem.GetLobSystemInstances();
      clientContext.Load(lobSystemInstanceCollection);
      clientContext.Load(entity);
      clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

      Microsoft.BusinessData.MetadataModel.LobSystemInstance lobSystemInstance = lobSystemInstanceCollection[0];

      Microsoft.BusinessData.MetadataModel.Collections.FilterCollection externalFiltersOnFieldCollection = entity.GetFilters(readListInstanceName);
```

Comment: Can anyone please answer this, if you found it. Thank you

Comment: sorry but I just exposed this value in my GUI and set the value to "Read List" by default or use what was provided by user.

Answer (score 1):

You must use these two dlls:

`Microsoft.SharePoint.BusinessData.Administration.Client.dll`
`Microsoft.Office.BusinessApplications.Diagnostics.dll`

Here is the code:

```
AdministrationMetadataCatalog catalog = AdministrationMetadataCatalog.GetCatalog(schemaRoot.Attribute("EntityNamespace").Value);

Microsoft.SharePoint.BusinessData.Administration.Client.Entity entityTemp = catalog.GetEntity(schemaRoot.Attribute("EntityNamespace").Value, schemaRoot.Attribute("EntityName").Value);

MethodInstanceCollection col = entityTemp.MethodInstances;

foreach (MethodInstance ins in col)
{
  if (ins.MethodInstanceType == MethodInstanceType.Finder)
  {
    readListInstanceName=ins.Name;   //your property which u mentioned before
    break;  
  }
}

//Now you can use your code
```

The `schemaRoot` property is the `SchemaXml` of your BCS field in the library.